# I have a set of variables that are correlated to the magnitude of my target variable but not with respect to the direction

Tags: regression, machine-learning

If I am expecting to predict returns by using say for instance average price volatility and volume in a time window, then these variables would not help predict the direction but would help improve the accuracy with respect to the magnitude. How do i combine these variables along with others which help predict direction in a regression model

Comment: This sounds like the sort of thing a [GARCH model with covariates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=garch+covariate) is intended to handle.